# UIActivityIndicator in tableviewcell Showing Up Late when loading the detailview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, android-activity, uiactivityindicatorview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `tableview` with responding `detialview`. In the `detailview` I have some images and labes that is loaded from a URL. I'm trying to add a `UIActivityindicatorview` to the cell to show that is loading. I have handled that but it shows up to late and does not disappear when I go back to the `tableview`. I have looked all over to find a simple solution, but failed...

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

ReaDetailViewController *reaDetail = [[ReaDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReaDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[activityView startAnimating];
[cell setAccessoryView:activityView];
[activityView release];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

    { 
    reaDetail.petImageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[exclusiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]; 

    reaDetail.petLabelString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[exclusiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"]]; 

    reaDetail.petLabelString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[exclusiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description1"]]; 

    reaDetail.petLabelString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[exclusiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description2"]]; 





    reaDetail.title = [[exclusiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]; 
}


// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reaDetail animated:YES];
[reaDetail release];


   }
```

Any help is very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to make the activity view to be animated while you load your view controller. The problem is the activity view won't start animating until you return from this selection method... which is about the time when your controller is ready to be pushed.

2 options then:

- You could exit from the method asap, calling `perfomSelector:onMainThread` to do the init steps of the view controller to be pushed
- Or even better, push the view controller asap, and do its init process in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods of this controller (you can add the activity controller in this new view).

If you pick the 1st option, you should call the `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method after you've pushed the new view controller and call `stopAnimating` on the indicator view from this `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method.